# Team Foundation Server: How to trigger or run a user script?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am new to Microsoft TFS, (I am used to Perforce - a similar tool).
How can we trigger or run a user script automatically when ever a particular event occurs
in TFS?

For instance, I want to run my java file when ever a change to any file has been saved through TFS.
(In perforce I used "Change-commit triggers" to achieve this)

Please help me out.

**EDIT**: After some research,
I figured that we need to "**Use the InvokeProcess activity to start a process (run a program) on the build server**" from the following [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg265783.aspx#Activity_InvokeProcess).

But How do I use it?? I am using a "Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012". Not able to figure out how to use InvokeProcess.. Please help me out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use the default template for invoke process. you need a custom template to set up invoke process.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff805001(v=vs.100).aspx ( check the invokeprocess part in this link )

Comment: Thank you for the response & useful link.
I don't have a visual studio or Windows workflow designer to follow the steps explained in the link. Is there any other alternate way or Do I have to install the s/w and try again?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with Build option available in Team explorer?